# When I execute docker build commands on Azure Devops YAML pipeline, an ARG specified in my Dockerfile does not appear to work

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Here is the script that I am running as part of my YAML pipeline:

```
- script: |
cd ./Server
ECHO ON
docker build -t image_name" -f path/to/Dockerfile --build-arg BUILD_VERSION=%COMPUTED_BUILD_VERSION% .
```

And here is the output from the script as it runs in Azure Devops:

```
D:\a\1\s\Server>docker build -t "image_name" -f path/to/Dockerfile --build-arg BUILD_VERSION=2018.12101 .
```

In particular, note that the %COMPUTED_BUILD_VERSION% environment variable is being passed in to the docker build command.

The Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
ARG BUILD_VERSION
RUN ECHO Building Service version %BUILD_VERSION%
RUN ECHO Building Service version $BUILD_VERSION
RUN ECHO Building Service version ${BUILD_VERSION}
```

And the output in Azure DevOps looks like this:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  101.4MB
Step 1/20 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
2.1-aspnetcore-runtime: Pulling from microsoft/dotnet
bce2fbc256ea: Already exists
6f2071dcd729: Pulling fs layer
85e382cad9c1: Pulling fs layer
354ed5b87a30: Pulling fs layer
4f039533731a: Pulling fs layer
96e328ca2eac: Pulling fs layer
4975b2dddfe9: Pulling fs layer
4f039533731a: Waiting
96e328ca2eac: Waiting
4975b2dddfe9: Waiting
354ed5b87a30: Verifying Checksum
354ed5b87a30: Download complete
85e382cad9c1: Verifying Checksum
85e382cad9c1: Download complete
96e328ca2eac: Verifying Checksum
96e328ca2eac: Download complete
4975b2dddfe9: Verifying Checksum
4975b2dddfe9: Download complete
4f039533731a: Verifying Checksum
4f039533731a: Download complete
6f2071dcd729: Verifying Checksum
6f2071dcd729: Download complete
6f2071dcd729: Pull complete
85e382cad9c1: Pull complete
354ed5b87a30: Pull complete
4f039533731a: Pull complete
96e328ca2eac: Pull complete
4975b2dddfe9: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:dcb2b8ad624a07f7acc3dc7eb4d8dcc8fb5870d5d86c74aec61a7b1545e60920
Status: Downloaded newer image for microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime
 ---> 3e1675085dc5
Step 2/20 : ARG BUILD_VERSION
 ---> Running in 569b03e478fe
Removing intermediate container 569b03e478fe
 ---> fd3325df3c1d
Step 3/20 : RUN ECHO Building Service version %BUILD_VERSION%
 ---> Running in 7d6a8e6b1c8b
Building
Service
version
%BUILD_VERSION%
Removing intermediate container 7d6a8e6b1c8b
 ---> cfb5403a8e41
Step 4/20 : RUN ECHO Building version $BUILD_VERSION
 ---> Running in 4731418f8d80
Building
Service
version
Removing intermediate container 4731418f8d80
 ---> 6ca6bfbf85e4
Step 5/20 : RUN ECHO Building Service version ${BUILD_VERSION}
 ---> Running in 3e1bfbdfbf94
Building
Service
version
```

Note that I simply CANNOT seem to get the Azure DevOps pipeline to recognize or print out the Dockerfile ARG parameter properly.  This is an issue because later in the Dockerfile (which I have omitted) the variable is used as an input to another step, which ends up failing.

Does anyone know how to make this work?  I feel like I must be missing something simple...

Answer (score 1):

I discovered eventually that the problem was that the shell was different than expected on Azure DevOps.  I read somewhere that the shell is, by default, CMD for Windows Containers.  This was true when running a `docker build` command locally on my machine.  However, in Azure Devops, the default shell was *powershell* instead of *cmd*.  Once I specifically selected a shell in my Dockerfile, this started working correctly for me.

Comment: Had same issue. Thanks for sharing.